# Teradata BTEQ Export Script Resulting Invalid Character in O/P File

Tags: teradata

## Here is my simple BTEQ Script

```
.LOGON 127.0.0.1/tduser,tduser
.EXPORT DATA FILE=C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Study\Google Drive\TD\BTEQ\Exported_File.txt
    SELECT      account_number
    FROM    samples.accounts
    WHERE   balance_current  < 500 ;
.EXPORT RESET
.QUIT
```

=====================================================================================

## The output of the script:

```
BTEQ 12.00.00.01 Tue Mar 26 19:58:59 2013

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.LOGON 127.0.0.1/tduser,

 *** Logon successfully completed.
 *** Teradata Database Release is 12.00.00.10
 *** Teradata Database Version is 12.00.00.10
 *** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
 *** Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.EXPORT DATA FILE=C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Study\Google Driv
e\TD\BTEQ\Exported_File.txt
 *** To reset export, type .EXPORT RESET
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
 SELECT   account_number
 FROM  samples.accounts
 WHERE  balance_current  < 500 ;

 *** Success, Stmt# 1 ActivityCount = 4
 *** Query completed. 4 rows found. One column returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.EXPORT RESET
 *** Output returned to console.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.QUIT
 *** You are now logged off from the DBC.
 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 0
```

=====================================================================================

Once, I check the file it shows invalid character's in the text file. Any possible workaround? Unicode problem? I am not sure.I even tried pasting the file content below, but its empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've looked over your log file and do not see anything abnormal. Can you replicate this issue with non-sensitive data and post the actual output?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for your time. I have saved the file in google drive and now I am able to open it through GDrive. My text output still shows up the invalid characters on my personal computer. And as I paste the output it looks like this, but in notepad there are * and square like characters. Possible notepad setup problem.  (    sayak r
      'Shilpa' 'Y
      sridipa n
      'Arvin' 'S'
      somdeb d
  
    sudip h
  2    sandip m

Comment: How is the column `account_number` defined?  Please add the output from running `show select * from samples.accounts` to your question so we can see the actual DDL.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below command for export in bteq :

.EXPORT REPORT FILE=filename...

I had faced the same issue with data file . After changing to this , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your filename in double quotes because of the whitespace in the path to the actual file.

**Original**

```
.EXPORT DATA FILE=C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Study\Google Drive\TD\BTEQ\Exported_File.txt
```

**Revised**

```
.EXPORT DATA FILE="C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Study\Google Drive\TD\BTEQ\Exported_File.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

change as below..

.EXPORT REPORT FILE=filename...